# Need grouped by Name

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns Id, Name, Program, Amount1, Amount2.

```
/* Create a table called NAMES */
CREATE TABLE NAMES(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text, Program char, Amount1 integer, Amount2 integer);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(1,'Abc','A',10  ,null);
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(2,'Abc','B',null,20);
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(3,'Def','A',30  ,null);
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(4,'Def','B',null,40);
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(5,'Pqr','A',50  ,null);
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(6,'Pqr','B',null,60);
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(7,'Xyz','A',70  ,null);
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(8,'Xyz','B',null,80);
COMMIT;

/* Display all the records from the table */
SELECT Name,Amount1,Amount2 FROM NAMES
group by Name;
```

Please help to get output grouped by Name and the Amount1, Amount2 in a single row as below.
HTML Table

```
Name    Amount1 Amount2
Abc     10      20
Def     30      40
Pqr     50      60
Xyz     70      80
```

Comment: Simply `SUM(column)`

Comment: When you "group by" Name, you get a *single* record for each Name. What *single* value of Amount1 and Amount2 do you want there? Min, Max, Sum, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple group by, with an aggregate function.

```
SELECT Name,SUM(Amount1),SUM(Amount2) 
FROM NAMES 
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use an aggregation function eg: max

```
SELECT Name,max(Amount1),max(Amount2) 
FROM NAMES
group by Name;
```

or as suggested  by GoranKutlaca sum()

```
SELECT Name,sum(Amount1),sum(Amount2) 
FROM NAMES
group by Name;
```

Comment: I believe SUM() would be more in the spirit of the data than MAX(), as comment on question suggested. It may be possible that both programs have some amount specified.

Comment: @GoranKutlaca  .. asnwer  updated . with your suggestion too